# Heat absorbing then releasing material

Tags: energy

I want to create a piece of sculpture 
That absorbs the suns rays in my family room during the day and released the heat in the evening. What would be  the best material for this? I was thinking a black granite

Comment: You might consider a thick black granite floor tile.  They wouldn't take up any of your living space.

Answer (score 1):

A material of high specific heat, coupled with another material of high thermal conductivity, might just do the trick. I would suggest water (high specific heat) taken in a metal tank(high thermal conductivity). Though this can be the best option, scientifically(talking about efficiency), it might not be the same aesthetically